# How to add array to a JComboBox

Tags: java, arrays, swing, combobox, jframe

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.ComboBoxModel;

public class test {
    public static String [][] myA;
    public static String i1;
    public static String i2;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String thisLine;
        String[] temp;
        String delimiter="\t";
        String [][] myA = new String[15][3];
            BufferedReader gg= new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filepath));
            for (int j=0; j<15; j++) {
                    thisLine=gg.readLine();
                    temp = thisLine.split(delimiter);
            for (int i = 0; i <3; i++) {
                myA[j][i]=temp[i];
            }}
            String i1 = myA[0][1];
            String i2 = myA[1][1];

            /*System.out.println(i1);
            System.out.println(i2);*/
          }

        }
```

I want to add a `menu.txt` to a `JComboBox` through the array; but when I
use this code at another frame class, it show nothing in the combobox.
Can someone help?

```
    String[] items = new String[] {test.i1,test.i2};
    JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(items);
    comboBox.setFont(new Font("Segoe Print", Font.BOLD, 20));
    comboBox.setBounds(147, 70, 419, 29);
    getContentPane().add(comboBox);
```

These are the text of Menu.txt:

```
Drink   Coffee  35
Drink   Latte   37
Drink   Mocha   37
Drink   Cappuccino  34
Drink   Hot Chocolate   34
Drink   Espresso    37
Drink   Hojicha Tea Latte   34
Drink   Java Chip   40
Drink   Ristretto Bianco    37
Salad   Salmon Salad    48
Salad   Chicken Garden Salad    42
Cake    Hazelnut&Chestnut Cheesecake    34
Cake    Chestnut Cheesecake 34
Cake    Chocolate Marquise  33
Cake    Lemon Tart  21
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this : 
- To set items of a JComboBox with Array after initialization

```
comboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(items));
```

Comment: Thank you,but it still shows nothing in the combobox